# Is there a way to replace the first '/' from a string conditionally?

Tags: regex, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.6, dealing with millions of rows of data. How do I replace forwardslash '/' with a dash '-'? The problem is we have forward slash after a few more words in the string and that we want to keep it, so basically if there are more than 1 forwardslash then replace the first one with a dash and do nothing for the second one and if there is only one forwardslash then do nothing as well.

I have tried `split_part()` and `substring()`, but none of them worked. First, I want to know in a select query and then I want a second step to replace it. In the below code, `column1` is `varchar` column and that's where I want to make a change.

```
Data Example:
Current - someName/abc-def-tn/more-random-names
Expected - someName-abc-def-tn/more-random-names
```

Note: someName is not a of a fixed length, so cannot use positioning.

```
select column1, 
reverse(split_part(reverse(column1), '/', 1)) as new_column_part1,
substring(column1, '[^/]*$') as new_url, as new_column_part2
from tableA
```

Comment: with `REGEXP_REPLACE`, you can capture the groups you want and replace the first slash with a dash.

Answer (score 3):

[**`regexp_replace()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) only replaces the **first occurrence** - unless you add `'g'` as optional 4th parameter, then it replaces all occurrences.

You want to replace the 1st occurrence, only if there is a 2nd. Two solutions:

```
SELECT col
     , CASE WHEN col ~ '/.*/'  -- only where there are two or more
            THEN regexp_replace(col, '/', '-')
            ELSE col  
       END AS new_col
     , regexp_replace(col, '/(?=.*/)', '-') AS new_col2
FROM   tbl;
```

`new_col2` does the same as `new_col` with a [positive lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE). More elegant, maybe, but I am not sure whether it's faster (or easier to read).

In an actual `UPDATE` I would do this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    col = regexp_replace(col, '/', '-')
WHERE  col ~ '/.*/';
```

This has the additional benefit that only rows are touched that actually need it. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Comment: `and then I want a second step to replace it`  .. That suggests you want to `UPDATE` a table to change existing columns?

Comment: Then consider the addition.

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

regexp_replace() replaces first occurrence of a string, for example:

```
regexp_replace('someName/abc-def-tn/more-random-names', '/', '-', '{1}')
```

let me know if this works

Comment: translate('someName/abc-def-tn/more-random-names', '/', ' ') didn't work, because it just translates '/' into no space, I want to replace it with a dash. So, I used translate('someName/abc-def-tn/more-random-names', '/', '-'), but the problem with this is that it translates even the second forwardslash which I don't want. Same goes for REPLACE function.

Comment: try now and let me know please